# Error 'Path reservation conflict' while starting meteor application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, meteor, bower

I've been working on a project for a while,
and when i tried adding bootstrap-timepicker from github using the following command :

```
"$ bower install bootstrap-timepicker"
```

i recieved an error saying "Path reservation conflict" while trying to start the meteor application, as shown bellow.

i tried uninstalling the pakage but then the error just change to a different path: :

```
"Path reservation conflict: packages/bower/jquery/jquery.js:
```

what does that error mean, and how can it be fixed?
and for the moment how can i atleast make it work, even without the bootstrap-timepicker, so i can carry on devloping?

```
 => Started proxy

 => Started MongoDB.  

    /home/varzager/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1lk318s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
    throw(ex);^

    Error: Path reservation conflict: packages/bower/angular/angular.js

    at [object Object]._.extend.reserve (/home/varzager/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1lk318s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/builder.js:241:15)

    at /home/varzager/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1lk318s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1150:15

    at /home/varzager/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1lk318s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1142:11
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a meteor-bower package problem.
It means that few different packages are bringing jquery through meteor-bower. would be good if you specify what packages your app uses (with including the .meteor/versions file)

3 options I can think about:

1. What version of meteor-bower do you use? They released new versions recently and it might address your problem. if not, I would anyway open an issue in their repo.
2. If it doesn't resolve just by updating, take a look at the package readme file, they explain how to install the modules in different locations with the .bowerrc to prevent collisions.
3. As Ramsay said, I've looked into bootstrap-timepicker meteor package's source code and it just bring the files so you can simply use that and it won't create conflicts for you and will definitely be easier.

Hope it helps